# Maximum slope for Vinyl flooring installation

Tags: basement, vinyl-flooring, basement-refinishing, vinyl

Dear Home Imporvement Experts,

I'm looking to install Vyinl flooring in my basement ( with subfloor like Dricore ) but the floor in basement has a slope of ~3.7-4 inches for 24 ft.

Will it be noticeable ? I'm hoping to make the slope consistent for the whole length.

[image: BASEMENT]
[image: Basement]

Comment: Is it noticeable now?  Unless you change the slope from what it is now, then the new floor will be the same.  Most flooring cares more about having a flat smooth floor more than slope,  You are what worries about slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is quite a drastic slope but I have seen it before and have installed vinyl, tile and carpet in similar setups.

Comments:

1. Dricore systems are for huge basements in cool climates.  NO WAY in he!! you should install their base system in that basement.   The pieces are heavy and if you have water you will want to move them.  Their dricore insulated flooring is a more suitable application.   Dricore makes good products but their core is way way more than most people need.
2. Slope doesn't matter, flatness does.   If your slope is continual its super easy.
3. You are going to do your homework when buying your flooring.  Most vinyl wants nothing under it.   You need to figure out what manufacturers will allow you to do this.
4. Your drywall is running way too low.   You will need to score it 2" up in most spots.
5. Carpet and tile should still be an option.   If you are worried about water, carpet does great and easy to dry out.   If you have continuous water, carpet is horrible.   If you have water ever 2 years carpet is great.
6. The hardest issue with flooring with the slope is the baseboards.   I have a solution but that is another question!

Comment: thank you for reply, much appreciated. Are you recommending to install vinyl tiles directly on concrete? I thought some sort of subfloor is needed.

Comment: Most pure vinyl flooring - the good rubber stuff - tells you nothing should be under.   If it works for you, that is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

If the new floor's pattern has straight lines, or a checker board type pattern, the slope may be more noticeable than other patterns.